# Do I need XAMPP for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, xampp

I already have experience with XAMPP by using Sublime Text3 as my code editor for web development. Recently, I installed Visual Studio using MSVC and installed packages: ASP.NET and Web development, Azure Development, Node.js Development, Python development. Do I still need to separately install XAMPP for mySQL database and so that I can use http://localhost to view the website I'll make using visual studio? Or is there a way for me to create a website without it and still run/view it in my browser using http://localhost or whatever setting? TIA for answering.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6AG5.png)

Comment: No..you wont need XAMPP. Visual Studio has IIS.

Comment: Xampp is for php mysql and apache. So no, you don't need it for aspnet, azure and node.

Comment: Follow up question: Would I need to keep VS Code open and run/compile the project website to view it in my browser or do I just need the localhost:port that it would provide and be able to open it in my browser without opening VS Code?